# How to build dynamic route from HTML POST variable in Flask Blueprint

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, forms, flask

I have POST request from the main page where a user submits company name into an HTML form. I also use Flask Blueprint called `company_bp`.

```
<form action="{{ url_for('company_bp.company') }}" class="search_form" method="post">
<input type="text" id="search_input" placeholder="Name" name="company_name" autocomplete="off">
<input type="submit" value="research">
                <ul id="search_list">

                </ul>
</form>
```

When I get `company_name` from the HTML form I would like to dynamically build a route for that specific company using its id in the database, not it's name which is what I got from the form.

```
@company_bp.route('/<company_id>',methods=['POST'])
def company(company_id):
    if request.method=='POST':
```

I am getting error which says that I need to provide `company_id` in the HTML form as such:

`{{ url_for('company_bp.company', company_id=company_id) }}`

I don't understand where and how to assign the company id to the variable `company_id`. I have id and company name from DB request via javascript but not clear how to put that id into the right variable.

## =====UPDATED

I have updated html file to change the form by adding a line with name="company_id":

```
 <form action="{{ url_for('company_bp.company', company_id=company_id) }}" class="search_form" id="search_form" method="post">
                <input type="text" id="search_input" placeholder="Name" name="company_name" autocomplete="off">
                <input type="hidden" name="company_id" id="co_id">
                <input type="submit" value="research">
</form>
```

When I inspect html form I see the id - 1456. However, when I submit form I am getting error `The requested URL was not found on the server`, and the problem that `POST` does not build correct url which should be `company/1456`, but only builds `company/` part.

Answer (score 1):

You can build the url with a placeholder Id to still use `url_for`, and then within your javascript, replace the placeholder with the correct value:

```
var url = "{{ url_for('company_bp.company', company_id='X') }}".replace("X", your_id);
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try. Is this javascript code - replace("X", your_id)? I am not familiar with JS enough

Comment: Yes, that will be in your (html) template

Comment: Totally confused. It looks like mix of html and js, and some python. FYI, I have jinja templating for front end.

Comment: It's only javascript - I'm going with what you've mentioned "I have id and company name from DB request via javascript", and what I've suggested would be added to this javascript. Could you add your current JS so I have that to work with?

Comment: JS works fine so far. I have now problem with getting value from Post request to python.

Comment: That’s pretty common but done with the ‘data’ parameter in your jquery, plenty of SO questions will be there to help